# Sorting an array of objects with a variable filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, javascript-objects

Im trying to filter my array of objects by the current month. Using animal crossing fish as an example

```
const fishData = {
   "fish_name": "Barreleye",
   "price": "15,000",
   "location": "Sea",
   "shadow_size": "Small",
   "n_March": true,
   "n_3": true,

 },
 {
   "fish_name": "Coelacanth",
   "price": "15,000",
   "location": "Sea (Rainy Days)",
   "shadow_size": "Largest",
   "n_3": true,

 }
]

var today = new Date();
var currentMonth = today.getMonth();

var fishMonth = `n_ + ${currentMonth}`;
console.log(fishMonth);
var filteredFish = fishData.filter(function(i) {
    return i.fishMonth == true;
});
```

now by return if i put `"n_3"` instead of `"fishMonth"` the code runs fine. I've checked the `"fishMonth"` and it does return `n_3`. What would be stoping this from working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are unnecessay characeter in your `fishMonth` variable, it should be:

```
var fishMonth = `n_${currentMonth}`;
```

and you also want to read the object's key so there has to be `return i[fishMonth] == true;`, try:

```js
const fishData = [{
   "fish_name": "Barreleye",
   "price": "15,000",
   "location": "Sea",
   "shadow_size": "Small",
   "n_March": true,
   "n_3": true,

 },
 {
   "fish_name": "Coelacanth",
   "price": "15,000",
   "location": "Sea (Rainy Days)",
   "shadow_size": "Largest",
   "n_3": true,

 }
]

var today = new Date();
var currentMonth = today.getMonth();

var fishMonth = `n_${currentMonth}`;
var filteredFish = fishData.filter(function(i) {
    return i[fishMonth] == true;
});
console.log(filteredFish);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the right key value without space and `+` and the right [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with brackets.

You could take some more changes, for example get the month directly from the instance and return directly the value of the wanted property.

```js
const
    fishData = [{ fish_name: "Barreleye", price: "15,000", location: "Sea", shadow_size: "Small", n_March: true, n_3: true }, { fish_name: "Coelacanth", price: "15,000", location: "Sea (Rainy Days)", shadow_size: "Largest", n_3: true }],
    fishMonth = `n_${(new Date).getMonth()}`,
    filteredFish = fishData.filter(fish => fish[fishMonth]);

console.log(filteredFish);
```

Finally, you could change the whole data structure and add the month as value to the objects and use something like a month property. This allowes to use a simple comparison with the value instead of using a compound key.

```js
const
    fishData = [{ fish_name: "Barreleye", price: "15,000", location: "Sea", shadow_size: "Small", n_March: true, month: 3 }, { fish_name: "Coelacanth", price: "15,000", location: "Sea (Rainy Days)", shadow_size: "Largest", month: 3 }],
    fishMonth = (new Date).getMonth(),
    filteredFish = fishData.filter(({ month }) => month === fishMonth);

console.log(filteredFish);
```